# Error Install less by CMD

Tags: cmd, npm, less

```
C:\Users\Elbarody>npm install -g less
```

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/less failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.122.238.10:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Elbarody\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-07-29T19_37_09_679Z-debug.log

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question

Answer (score 0):

`ETIMEDOUT` is caused when a response is not received in given time.

Things to try:

- Make sure you can ping `http://registry.npmjs.org`
- Connect to a `VPN` & try downloading again
- Try again at a later time

Comment: this is same problem in install angular. but i make every thing to edit it. i make sure from ping and again install at a later time but i can't solve it

Comment: @MohamedSamy maybe they're having network issues at the node you're accessing. All I can suggest is try using a VPN to see if you manage to get it to work then.

Comment: @MohamedSamy did this help you?